# How do I construct a spring simulation without animation?

Tags: modeling, physics, rigid-body-simulation

I want to model a mass on spring simulation; but not by using animation. How do I do this?

Comment: You may find your answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39979/how-can-i-make-springs-stretch-and-squeeze-depending-on-the-cube-movements/42191